# How can I pass parameters from a web application (JSP) to a Flex application (mxml file)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

In my enterprise web application I have a menu item ( struts menu ) which calls for a Flex web application.

Here "LPort"  is  my flex web app and "Main" is my EAR. 
I can go to my flex application but hwo can I pass paramters from my JSP to the MXML file.

Comment: Sorry if you did not understand my question. I am not asking how to google ?? I was askign for communication between 2 web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the Flex app (Flash swf) embedded in your JSP - my suggestion is to use "FlashVars" to pass parameters from the JSP to the Flex application.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="LPort.swf" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="paramA=<%=paramA%>&paramB=<%=paramB%>" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
  <param name="menu" value="false"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <embed src="LPort.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7" id="Logbook"
            width="100%" height="100%" name="LPort" align="middle"
            FlashVars="paramA=<%=paramA%>&paramB=<%=paramB%>"
    menu="false"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            wmode="opaque"
            allowScriptAccess="always"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
</object>
```

Then in your Flex application you can access these parameters as follows (I assume a cast of String).

```
if (Application.application.parameters.paramA != undefined)
{
  myFlexVarA = String(Application.application.parameters.paramA);
}
if (Application.application.parameters.paramB != undefined)
{
  myFlexVarB = String(Application.application.parameters.paramB);
}
```